# Quick Completions in HTML?

Tags: html

I've been watching some 'codecasts' on CSSDeck.com, and I frequently see people typing things like this: `ul>li*7>a` to create a large amount of HTML very quickly.  That code would generate this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href=""></a></li>
  <li><a href=""></a></li>
  <li><a href=""></a></li>
  <li><a href=""></a></li>
  <li><a href=""></a></li>
  <li><a href=""></a></li>
  <li><a href=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

As seen on: http://cssdeck.com/labs/creating-sweet-3d-pagination

What plugin is this?

Comment: it's called "zen coding" http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It used to be called Zen Coding, but is now called [Emmet](http://docs.emmet.io/).

There are plugins for most editors, including Sublime Text 2 (which I'd recommend if you aren't already sorted for one!)

For Sublime Text if you are using [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control), it's a simple `package install emmet` away.

Comment: I am on Sublime Text 2, and I searched a bit for plugins to do this, but I had no idea what it was called.  Thanks!

Comment: Correct. Much like vim isn't an IDE.